# LIRC zero key code 0x10001d0f

Tags: c, controller, infrared, lirc

I am using LIRCD to capture the keys I press on my remote control. I am able to capture all the keys except zero, when I press zero it doesn't respond at all. This is what I have in lircd.conf. All keys are working except zero

```
  begin codes
      0               0x10001d0f
      1               0x1000590f
      2               0x10006900
      3               0x10007901
      4               0x10001c0e
      5               0x10002c0f
      6               0x10003c00
      7               0x10004c01
      8               0x10005c02
      9               0x10006c03
      CURSOR_LEFT     0x1000580e
      CURSOR_RIGHT    0x1000680f
      CURSOR_DOWN     0x1000480d
      CURSOR_UP       0x1000380c
      CHANNEL_UP      0x10007a02
      CHANNEL_DOWN    0x10005a00
      OK              0x10000f00
      EXIT            0x10005b01
      MENU            0x10002f02
```

Comment: This seems more a problem with LIRC, so I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg do you mean that LIRC can't read zero? may be, but I am also not sure that what I am doing it correct or not. I have added more code in start, if that has something to do with it. I have very limited knowledge, any help will be appreciated

Comment: LIRCD http://www.lirc.org/html/lircd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved.

LIRCD was perfectly fine, the issue was with the interface I was using to send signals

Comment: If you think this issue may be of any interest to others in the future, please try to provide more details on the problem and the solution. Until then the question is off topic.